# What file names should I test my application with?

Tags: java, file, testing, jfilechooser

My application involves file loading and saving (windows only), the user can enter any name they like.

I want to ensure I have enough checks and validation to prevent any errors occurring due to the name that the user selects.

What are some names that commonly cause problems, for which I should test that my application will work with?

Comment: Could you clarify "commonly cause problems"? What sort of things are you anticipating? The file name alone shouldn't cause any issues. If the input is in a file named "myimage.pdf.txt.html.png", everything should still work assuming the format and content is readable to your program.

Comment: @deyur I mean sometimes certain names will cause issues in a program, such as having spaces in the name, or slashes. Exactly, *should* still work, but I'd like to test it to make 100% sure, so multiple extensions could be one.

Comment: Could you guys who have voted to close please explain why you have done so?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but there is little potential for an answer to this question to contain factual information.

Comment: Better phrasing for this question would be "what characters are illegal in Windows filenames?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..(windows only)....What are some names that commonly cause problems, for which I should test that my application will work with?

You should avoid file names such as,

```
CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL, COM0-9, LPT0-9
```

and following characters are not allowed in file name,

```
^./\\:*?\"<>|
```

Please check this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) link for more information,

> I want to ensure I have enough checks and validation to prevent any
>   errors occurring due to the name that the user selects.

And User won't be able to create file which contains above values (at least without any hack) and so that user can not select one of those files.

You can simply avoid file names by the use of regExp.

```
(?i)(COM\\d{1}| LPT\\d{1} | CON | PRN | AUX |CLOCK$ | NUL)//TO avoid names
```

Comment: Can you quickly explain what CON PRN etc. are?

Comment: Those are reserved file names that can not be used.. check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) link for more

Comment: OMG the first two reserved names break my application! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Allow only Alphanumeric characters, you can do that by using Apache Commons Lang:
  `StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(file_name)`
- You need to have a business logic, if user provide the same file name again, Your logic should be based on below three points:

  - Should you throw error and notify user the file already exist.
  - Override existing file.
  - Amend existing file.

Comment: That would only allow prevention of saving weird files, a file could be from elsewhere and still have a weird name which would then be loaded into my application

Comment: If the file is from elsewhere you may want to do the same check alphanumeric etc. however there could be case when user would like to retain the same file name.

Comment: yes the filename should not change

Comment: also isAlphanumeric will exclude things like _ right? which is a perfectly valid (and common) file name

Comment: It will exclude like _. It's just an example. You can use simple regex for the characters which you would like to include.